# Incorrect number formatting in Pentaho Report

Tags: pentaho, number-formatting, pentaho-report-designer

I'm using Pentaho Report designer 3.9 for a legacy project that has some reports that should support different languages (English, Spanish and Euskera).

I have a problem with the number formatting. While in English and Spanish numbers show properly (`#.###,##` in Spanish and `#,###.##` in English), in Euskera numbers are shown the same way that are shown in English, but they should be shown the same as Spanish.

I've tried setting the language as `eu`, as `eu_ES` and `es-ES` but I haven't suceeded.

Have anyone had a similar problem?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Number format field  will not directly work for multi-language report.
In my current project we are using MySQL database and handling multi-language number format at query level and using text-field displaying it into report.

Comment: My first aproach was to define number formats in the translation files and look up for that resource using `RESOURCELOOKUP` but since English and Spanish translation did it automatically I was trying to find a more friendly solution. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to use the mask in the Text Output to generate a CSV, the execution was ignored the mask to convert "0.00" to "0,00". I found that the problem was in the Oracle sql query with a TO_CHAR ( ) in the column, which caused masks to be ignored.